# Reduce outgoing bandwidth in ffmpeg

Tags: networking, bandwidth, rackspace, ffmpeg

I have a server in Rackspace with some `ffmpeg` processes listening to audio streaming. Off course when listening to streamings the incoming network traffic is high, and this is ok. But I noticed that there is also a considerable outgoing network traffic (about 1KB/sec / process). Is there any way to reduce this?

```
  PID USER     PROGRAM      DEV        SENT      RECEIVED       
14921 ubuntu   ffmpeg       eth0       1.704      67.070 KB/sec
15039 ubuntu   ffmpeg       eth0       1.120      10.513 KB/sec
13985 ubuntu   ffmpeg       eth0       1.023      41.767 KB/sec
15012 ubuntu   ffmpeg       eth0       1.008       5.430 KB/sec
13361 ubuntu   ffmpeg       eth0       0.967      28.596 KB/sec
14913 ubuntu   ffmpeg       eth0       0.953      21.550 KB/sec
15044 ubuntu   ffmpeg       eth0       0.848       0.909 KB/sec
13842 ubuntu   ffmpeg       eth0       0.810      12.917 KB/sec
14190 ubuntu   ffmpeg       eth0       0.773      16.160 KB/sec
14799 ubuntu   ffmpeg       eth0       0.722      12.406 KB/sec
```

Answer (score 2):

The outgoing bandwidth is likely TCP ACK packets, in which case no, you can't do anything about this bandwidth short of switching to a UDP- based stream if it's available.

Comment: Even UDP would send something back to let the server know you are still listening.

Comment: Yes, certainly, but upstream bandwidth would likely be significantly lower, which is what the OP was asking about.